# Add new column that finds percentage off value in existing column

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage

In Oracle, I want to write a SELECT query that will find 1.75 percentage off an existing column that has whole numbers in each row and round it to the nearest dollar.

I have somewhat of my query down, but can't figure out how to write the formula to perform the percentage off calculation.

```
SELECT R.LAST_NAME, O.RENT_FEE, ROUND(RENT_FEE,0) AS DISCOUNT
FROM ROOM_UNIT R, OWNER O
WHERE R.OWNER_NUM = O.OWNER_NUM
```

Comment: I can't believe you are asking how to apply a percentage to a number... besides, you posted the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711290/decrease-all-values-in-a-column-by-1-percentage) some days ago. Please do some effort and study at least the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From math lessons we know that discounting by `x` percent is equivalent to multiplying by

```
(1-x/100)
```

In your case, discounting by 1.75% means multiplying by, `(1 - 0.0175)` or `0.9825`:

```
SELECT R.LAST_NAME, O.RENT_FEE, ROUND((1 - 0.0175) * RENT_FEE,0) AS DISCOUNT
FROM ROOM_UNIT R, OWNER O --          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
WHERE R.OWNER_NUM = O.OWNER_NUM
```

Comment: Why not just write `(1 - 0.0175) * RENT_FEE`?  It seem clearer and less prone to error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much for a great suggestion! It is indeed easier to read, and the optimizer will optimize away the subtraction.